# Array: Automatically get children from project

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I need a script that put into a public array all the images in a folder in the project.

Since i'm working with more than 200 images for array, it becomes pretty annoying to place all those images manually into the public array.

[image]

Comment: what did you try already? You know how to create a loop? How should we know to which level you need help when you don't provide *any* own attemps.

Comment: This is basically already supported built-in .. see [zambari's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262882/7111561) ... so I would actually close this question as asking for UI feature ^^ Automatically searching for those can lead to all kinds of unexpected behavior (from a user perspective) so I would discourage from doing this ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can drag them all at once. Use the padlock to keep the editor locked, select all in the Project Window, using shift, than drag all selected images onto the field name in inspector (not into the first slot). Doing it via code is also possible but a little bit cumbersome